# hadoop copy file to current directory from hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop

I want to re write the function of copy file from hdfs to local

```
    String src = args[0]; // hdfs 
    String dst = args[1]; // local path

    /*
     * Prepare the input and output filesystems
     */
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem inFS = FileSystem.get(URI.create(src), conf);
    FileSystem outFS = FileSystem.get(URI.create(dst), conf);

    /*
     * Prepare the input and output streams
     */

    FSDataInputStream in = null;
    FSDataOutputStream out = null;
    // TODO: Your implementation goes here...
    in = inFS.open(new Path(src));

    out = outFS.create(new Path(dst),
            new Progressable() {
        /*
         * Print a dot whenever 64 KB of data has been written to
         * the datanode pipeline.
         */
        public void progress() {
            System.out.print(".");
        }
    });
```

(1) when I set the local path to my current director

-->    `JAVA I/O error. mkdirs failed to create file`

(2)  when I set the path to a non exist folder

--> a new folder is created and my copied file is inside.

What should I do?

I beleive I should not use filesystem.create()?, am I?

**EDIT**

a related filesystem library link:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#create(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)

Comment: Maybe a permission issue?

Comment: how can I check if it's permission issue. I can use mkdir to create new file normally under current directory

Comment: Run your code with admin privileges.

Comment: do you mean using 'sudo'. I have a file not found exception. Also it is a virtual machine hosted by others, does it stop me from doing this

Comment: Hmm, try checking if the folder is present and only then create it.

Comment: But I want to put the file in the existing(current directory) folder, what function should I use instead of create